# How to detect someone's sim card is active or not

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have daily 40 to 50 phone numbers. Currently we are manually calling to each to detect each one's status like phone number is active(if call ringing) or not.I want to  do this programmatically. Is it possible, to programmatically call each number and if phone ring is going on then set it's status active otherwise deactive?

Comment: i think truecaller application is also some what like your concept did you tried..

Comment: @prabhakaran, TrueCaller not seems to meet this requirement.It's used to block unwanted call and getting identification of caller.while mu intension in reverse to truecaller. we have already list of phone number that we check it's active or not.By the way thanks for reply. please update if you find some helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but better to use sms Delivery Report to check in android u may create a program in which if it shows delivery report than automatically added to active otherwise inactive

```
BroadcastReceiver sendBroadcastReceiver = new sentReceiver();
    BroadcastReceiver deliveryBroadcastReciever = new deliverReceiver();;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        try {
            unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    send_sms.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (textView.getText().toString().equals("")
                        | textView.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
                    Toast.makeText(SendSMS.this, enter_ph_no, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                } else {


                        sendSMS(textView.getText().toString(), "sms_content");
                        finish();


                }

            }
        });
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);


    }

    class deliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sms_delivered,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




  //Here you write any code to put the number in DB or filebased etc
     that number is active

                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sms_not_delivered,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    class sentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sms_sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                startActivity(new Intent(SendSMS.this, ChooseOption.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for worderfull idea that we can check status using SMS deliver message (+1) for it. I implemnting your given code and update you soon.